# Как будет быстрее

Tags: php

Нужно удалить все значения сессии кроме одного. как быстрее - циклом или в лоб?

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val) {
    if ($key !== 'one') {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

vs

```
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['login']); 
unset($_SESSION['pass']); 
unset($_SESSION['ip']);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы попали в западню, называемую "преждевременной оптимизацией". Прежде чем оптимизировать аналогичные участки кода, спросите себя - вы вообще замечаете проблему в их скорострельности? Выполняются ли они дольше миллисекунды? Ответом, конечно, будет "нет", а с точки поддерживаемости кода нужно писать просто читаемый код, отдавая предпочтение более удобочитаемому коду. В конечно счете время, потраченное на разработку кода будет больше того выигрыша, который мог бы быть достигнут такими микрооптимизациями.

С вашего позволения я сделал микробенч:

```
<?php

function benchA($data) {
     unset($data['a']);
     unset($data['b']);
     unset($data['c']);
     unset($data['d']);
}

function benchB($data) {
     foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          unset($data[$key]);
     }
}

$data = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4,];

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    benchA($data);
}
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Bench A: ' . $time . ', ops/sec: ' . (100000 / $time) . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    benchB($data);
}
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Bench B: ' . $time . ', ops/sec: ' . (100000 / $time) . PHP_EOL;
```

> Bench A: 0.25466990470886, ops/sec: 392665.16439907
>   Bench B: 0.37867712974548, ops/sec: 264077.21022712

Конечно, цикл имеет некоторые побочные расходы. Но они настолько невелики, что этой конструкцией вы выиграли порядка 3,7E-6 (0,0000037) секунды - ***любой*** запрос к базе данных будет длиться в **сотни** раз дольше (я уж молчу про инициализацию интерпретатора, у которой погрешность времени в запуске много раз сожрет всю разницу). Более того, даже если бы эта разница была существенной, ею бы все равно стоило пренебречь просто ради сохранения читаемости кода (и, кстати говоря, читаемый код подразумевает отступы).

Другими словами, не задумывайтесь над такими вещами. Пишите читаемый код, а если будут проблемы с производительностью - смотрите в сторону более красивых решений, нежели перебор массива руками - кэширование, более оптимизированные алгоритмы, распараллеливание, и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю так:

```
$session_value = $_SESSION[$key];
unset($_SESSION);
$_SESSION[$key] = $session_value;
```